# Do you any free tools for tuning program that run in parallel on Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading, performance

What free tools do you know that can be used for tuning multithreaded applications?

If there are any.

Answer (score 0):

[Intel Parallel Studio](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-parallel-studio-home/) is not free, but it has evaluation period. And it looks like the most powerfull tool.

Comment: Yes, I know about that. I just wondered if there are something else.
It requires C++ Visual Studio commercial version. It does not work with Exress.

Comment: I don't think there are lot of such free tools. You could check CHESS project - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/ but it will be commercial also.